# PFSense refuses IPv6 Gateway Config

Tags: routing, ipv6, pfsense

I am configuring a PFSense box to use as a firewall.
It's config should be:

```
IPv6 address: 2a01:4f8:a0:241b::1
Gateway: fe80::1
```

But when I try to add this gateway in the gui, PFSense refuses and tells me it cannot do this:

[image]

And when I use the CLI it tells me this:

```
Not in subnet!
```

I tried this config on a Windows box hooked up to the same switch/router, and not only did it not complain, it works as in intended and can contact services like google using this gateway.
I have no clue as to why PFSense would not accept this config.

Comment: I understand this, but I the way the server hosting company has set this up is that I can only connect to his gateway router by connecting to the link-local address. As I stated, I did the same config on a windows server and it works perfectly fine using the link local as a gateway and is accessible from my own computer on IPv6.
Basicly I want to use a link local as a gateway.

Comment: @EEAA Link-local addresses are perfectly valid for routing IPv6, provided the interface is specified or can be determined. This is a significant change from IPv4, where link-local addresses usually aren't present (and when they appear, usually indicate a problem).

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's right. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I was able to fix this:

Go to System/Routing/Gateways.
Here you can add/edit a gateway like fe80::1 and set it a gateway/default for any interface.